# FullCalendar jQuery Pluggin, Events Disappearing after drag

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm having a silly issue here with FullCalendar, where once I run my callback function the event disappears off the page.

This is my settings for the calendar

```
var calendarSettings = {
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    events: '/ajaxCalenderEvents',
    timeFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    eventDrop: function(object){
        calendar.drop(object);
        //console.log(object);
    }
}
```

This is the function the eventDrop event calls,

```
calendar = {
    drop: function(o){
        o.start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(o.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        o.end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(o.end, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        $.post('/ajaxMoveDateRange', {data: o}, function(data){
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

However when I drag the event and drop it, it fires the ajax request perfectly however the event disappears.

BUT.

If I do it like:

```
var calendarSettings = {
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    events: '/ajaxCalenderEvents',
    timeFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    eventDrop: function(o){
        o.start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(o.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        o.end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(o.end, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        $.post('/ajaxMoveDateRange', {data: o}, function(data){
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

and have the function inline, it works fine.

However the file structure/model we're using means we need to format it as i previously had it, calling the external function.

Does anybody know of any reasons that this could be happening? I've tried returning true and stuff, and nosed around the documentation but cannot find anything, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, I've narrowed it down to the $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); lines. when i run this function it clears the calendar...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.
Just so you know, eventDrop is not the same as drop. eventDrop is for internal dragging and dropping of events that are already on the calenar, and drop is for dragging external events onto the calendar.

Anyhow try

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy\'-\'MM\'-\'-\'dd');
```